# Filter customers with atleast 3 transactions a year for the past 2 years Presto/SQL

Tags: sql, date, select, group-by, presto

I have a table of customer transactions called **cust_trans** where each transaction made by a customer is stored as one row. I have another col called **visit_date** that contains the transaction date. I would like to filter the customers who transact atleast **3** times a year for the past **2** years.

The data looks like below

```
Id          visit_date    
----        ------        
1           01/01/2019     
1           01/02/2019     
1           01/01/2019      
1           02/01/2020      
1           02/01/2020      
1           03/01/2020      
1           03/01/2020      
2           01/02/2019 
3           02/04/2019
```

I would like to know the customers who visited atleast 3 times every year for the past two years

ie. I want below output.

```
id    
---       
1
```

From the customer table only one person visited atleast 3 times for 2 years.

I tried with below query but it only checks if total visits greater than or equal to 3

```
select id
 from 
  cust_scan
         GROUP  by 
         id
         having count(visit_date) >= 3
         and year(date(max(visit_date)))-year(date(min(visit_date))) >=2
```

I would appreciate any help, guidance or suggestions

Comment: What do YOU mean by last 2 years?  Calendar year?

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to generate a list of distinct `id`s, cross join it with the last two years, and then bring the original table with a `left join`. You can then aggregate to count how many visits each `id` had each year. The final step is to aggregate again, and filter with a `having` clause

```
select i.id
from (
    select i.id, y.yr, count(c.id) cnt
    from (select distinct id from cust_scan) i
    cross join (values 
        (date_trunc('year', current_date)), 
        (date_trunc('year', current_date) - interval '1' year) 
    ) as y(yr)
    left join cust_scan c 
        on  i.id = c.id
        and c.visit_date >= y.yr
        and c.visit_date <  y.yr + interval '1' year
    group by i.id, y.yr
) t
group by i.id
having min(cnt) >= 3
```

Another option would be to use two correlated subqueries:

```
select distinct id
from cust_scan c
where 
    (
        select count(*) 
        from cust_scan c1 
        where 
            c1.id = c.id
            and c1.visit_date >= date_trunc('year', current_date)
            and c1.visit_date <  date_trunc('year', current_date) + interval '1' year
    ) >= 3
    and (
        select count(*) 
        from cust_scan c1 
        where 
            c1.id = c.id
            and c1.visit_date >= date_trunc('year', current_date) - interval '1' year
            and c1.visit_date <  date_trunc('year', current_date)
    ) >= 3
```

Comment: but this doesn't check if they did atleast 3 transactions every year for both year or two year.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you mean calendar years.  I think I would use two levels of aggregation:

```
select ct.id
from (select ct.id, year(visit_date) as yyyy, count(*) as cnt
      from cust_trans ct
      where ct.visit_date >= '2019-01-01'  -- or whatever
      group by ct.id
     ) ct
group by ct.id
having count(*) = 2 and  -- both year
       min(cnt) >= 3;    -- at least three transactions
```

If you want the last two complete years, just change the `where` clause in the subquery.

You can use a similar idea -- of two aggregations -- if you want the last two years relative to the current date.  That would be two full years, rather than 1 and some fraction of the current year.